# Day and night I stand around

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I stand around day and night,
>   A crimson tourist's delight.
>   People used to queue up just to chat with me,
>   But now I'm lonely and forgotten
>   I'm just a money loving oversized novelty.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you a

> Telephone box
> [image]

I stand around day and night,

> It can't move at any time (except maybe Doctor Who's)

A crimson tourist's delight.

> It is bright red and are quite rare

People used to queue up just to chat with me,

> People queued to speak on the phone as it was the only phone available at the time

But now I'm lonely and forgotten,

> But mobiles where invented so the telephone box was no longer needed

I'm just a money loving oversized novelty

> Reference to how large it is and how you had to insert coins to make a call